# O(sumof(n)) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Question is simple and straightforward: is there such thing as a time complexity of
[image: O(sumof(n))]

and is this the proper way to write it?
I am asking because this program I wrote:

```
    def check(self, front, s, back):
        if(s[front:back] == s[front:back][::-1]): 
            return s[front:back]
        else: 
            return self.check(front, s, back-1)

    def checkIter(self, front, s, back, longest):
        r = self.check(front, s, back)
        if(len(r) >= len(longest)): longest = r
        if(front < back):
            return self.checkIter(front+1,s,back, longest)
        else:
            return longest
        
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        return self.checkIter(0,s,len(s),"")
```

on input of `longestPalindrome('cbbd')` it runs ~10 times producing the ouputs:

`"cbbd" "cbb" "cb" "c" "bbd" "bb" "b" "bd" "b" "d"`. On a simalar input of `longestPalindrome('cbbda')` gives:
`"cbbda" "cbbd" "cbb" "cb" "c" "bbda" "bbd" "bb" "b" "bda" "bd" "b" "da" "d" "a"` So this can't be O(n)

Comment: You probably meant `O(n)`.

Comment: no I mean O(n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1)

Comment: Remeber for big O time complexity we take the upper bound, similar to a limit. So once you simplify your expression O(n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1) will will be left with O(n)

Comment: @JasonGerard check edit please

Comment: @JasonGerard that is straight up wrong.  You are adding `n` factors, each contributing some amount proportional to `n` itself-  the total is `O(n ^ 2)`.  More formally, you can show that its actually the sum of natural numbers up to `N`, or `O(N * (N+1) / 2)` -> `O(N ^ 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified sum is equal to `n(n+1)/2`. Hence, it is in `O(n^2)`.